# How to skip over missing values while transforming DataFrame in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, missing-data

I would like to transform each element in a column in a Julia DataFrames.DataFrame but skip over missing values in doing so (let them stay in the table intact).

As a simple example, we could do it in this way:

```
using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta

@linq DataFrame(mode=[1,2,missing]) |>
transform(
    mode = map(x->(if x === missing missing elseif x in ([0:5...]) x+1 else missing end), :mode)
)
```

But it looks more or less cluttered. Would there be more elegant or concise ways?

I read Query.jl and DataFramesMeta.jl docs hoping to find a method by which I don't have to code skipping over missing values explicitly.

**EDIT:**
I think the following is the best I can think of:

```
using DataFrames, DataFramesMeta, DataValues

skipmap(f, c) = map(x->(if x===missing missing else f(x) end), c)

@linq DataFrame(mode=[1,2,missing]) |>
transform(
    mode = skipmap(x->if x in ([0:5...]) x+1 else x end, :mode)
)
```

I think it would be great if map() is extended in a way that it accepts a third parameter y (hence map(f,c,y)) and keep those elements intact in the array if they belong to y.

Comment: check the `skipmissing` function

Comment: skipmissing() drops missing elements from the array entirely. but what I would like to do is simply ignore them, let them stay in the array and move on to the next non missing element to process.

Comment: Why do you need to skip over them? Shouldn't `transform(mode = :mode .+ 1)` suffice?

Comment: In this case it sufficies as `+` and `in` will propagate `missing` but not all functions do this and that is why `passmissing` is provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`passmissing` that is exported by DataFrames.jl does what you want.
For example you can use such one-liner:

```
julia> passmissing(x -> x + (x in 0:5)).([1,2,missing,4,5,6])
6-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 2
 3
  missing
 5
 6
 6
```

additionally you can use broadcasting as `+` and `in` functions implicitly return `missing` if you pass them `missing`, e.g.:

```
julia> x = [1,2,missing,4,5,6]
6-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 1
 2
  missing
 4
 5
 6

julia> x .+ in.(x, Ref(0:5))
6-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 2
 3
  missing
 5
 6
 6
```

or

```
julia> (v -> v + in(v, 0:5)).(x)
6-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 2
 3
  missing
 5
 6
 6
```

Comment: passmissing exactly does what I want. 
To deal with something like passmissing(x->x in 0:5 ? x : missing).([missing,2,3]) should require using passmissing. The function seems currently not mentioned in the DataFrame doc. Thank you for the other useful tips too!

Comment: This function is defined in Missings.jl and is only re-exported by DataFrames.jl. It is explained in the last section of this tutorial https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial/blob/master/03_missingvalues.ipynb.

Comment: Oh you are the author!. Thank you for the additional gems!

Comment: how do you do this with nested functions? does it need a "passmissing" for each function?

Comment: What do you mean by "nested function" exactly? Maybe you can open a separate question with an example?